# can't write right to left language in text block

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I can't write right to left language in a text block in windows-phone c#.
I search for it here , but its all about the alignment of a text box

```
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="12,12,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="603" Width="429"/>
```

I set horizontal alignment to right but its about alignment of text block itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set FlowDirection property to RightToLeft:

```
FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
```